# Replace String In Entity Framework 5 Query

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5, and I want to replace a couple characters in a field when the query is executed from the database.

Is there any way to do this with say maybe a `EntityTypeConfiguration`?

Or somehow a transparent way?

Comment: Why don't you just provide an additional property or method on your object that returns the value in the desired format?

Comment: "when the query is executed from the database." ??

Comment: Yeah, I want to say to EF, when you retrieve this field, replace these characters with null.

Comment: So you want to make some field null?